# Android Full Screen blocking view like Google Calendar FAB

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to make a Floating Action Button Menu in my app. It should look like the FAB in the Google Calendar app, which is the kind of a active FAB shown by the Material Design Guideline:

See here:
https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button

Under "The floating action button changes color on focus and lifts upon being selected." there are two videos. The right one shows what this menu should look like. I have a menu like button that works perfectly but what I cannot achive is this gray background that blocks the whole UI (like an alert) with the action and task bar...

Normal:

[image: normal]

And selected:

[image: selected]

As you can see, the material design guideline tells us that a selected FAB should block the whole UI. But I don't know how...

So what I have at the moment:
I have a global_fab.xml that holds my two FABs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/fab_background"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/global_fab_mini"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_credentials_light"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/cool_grey"
            app:fabSize="mini" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/global_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_light"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

This FAB has a corresponding ViewGroup Class:

```
package de.mycompany.ui.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.mycompany.package.android.R;
import com.mycompany.package.android.databinding.GlobalFabBinding;

public class GlobalFABView extends FrameLayout implements IGlobalFABView {

    private GlobalFabBinding globalFABViewBinding;
    private Listener listener;

    private boolean fabMenuOpen = false;

    public GlobalFABView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public GlobalFABView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        globalFABViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.global_fab, this, false);

        addView(globalFABViewBinding.getRoot());

        this.globalFABViewBinding.globalFab.setOnClickListener(this::globalFabClicked);
        this.globalFABViewBinding.fabBackground.setOnClickListener(this::backgroundClicked);
    }

    private void globalFabClicked(View v) {
        this.listener.mainFabClicked();
    }
    private void backgroundClicked(View v) {
        this.listener.backgroundClicked();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggleFabMenu() {
        Animation fabAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), this.fabMenuOpen ?
                R.anim.global_fab_close :
                R.anim.global_fab_open);
        final boolean fabMenuOpen = this.fabMenuOpen;
        if (!fabMenuOpen) {
            globalFABViewBinding.globalFabMini.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        globalFABViewBinding.fabBackground.setVisibility(
                fabMenuOpen ? GONE : VISIBLE
        );
        fabAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // Nothing to do.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (fabMenuOpen) {
                        globalFABViewBinding.globalFabMini.setVisibility(GONE);
                    globalFABViewBinding.globalFab.setSelected(!fabMenuOpen);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // Nothing to do.
            }
        });
        globalFABViewBinding.globalFabMini.startAnimation(fabAnimation);
        this.fabMenuOpen = !fabMenuOpen;
    }
}
```

My menu opens and closes without problems (I have two anim xmls for this). The Background RelativeLayout (`+id/fab_background`) is there to handle the "click anywhere and close menu" event.

Now I add this into any activty I want it:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:id="@+id/fab_holder">

            <include layout="@layout/app_bar_with_progress_bar" android:id="@+id/appbar"/>

            <de.mycompany.ui.view.HomeView
                android:id="@+id/home_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appbar" />

            <de.mycompany.ui.view.GlobalFABView
                android:id="@+id/global_fab_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post your `xml` layout?

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya added my xml stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got this.

in order to lay a new layer over the whole screen we need to start a new activity that is transparent. 
I created an activity that holds the menu. Into my normal activity I only added one Floating Action Button. In the click action of this, I open my `MenuActivity` without animations, so I can animate the appearance of the Floating Action Button Menu. This is my Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fab_background"
            android:background="@color/fab_menu_background"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/global_fab_mini"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_credentials_light"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/cool_grey"
            app:fabSize="mini" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/global_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_light"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/fab_mini_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab_mini_label"
            android:background="@drawable/fab_label_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/global_fab"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/global_fab"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/fab_main_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fab_main_label"
            android:background="@drawable/fab_label_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/fab_mini_label"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fab_mini_label"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

In my Activity I have this function:

```
    public void toggleFabMenu() {
        Animation fabAnimation =     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), this.fabMenuOpen ?
                R.anim.global_fab_close :
                R.anim.global_fab_open);
        Animation labelAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), this.fabMenuOpen ?
                R.anim.global_fab_labels_close :
                R.anim.global_fab_labels_open);
        Animation backgroundAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), this.fabMenuOpen ?
                R.anim.global_fab_menu_background_close :
                R.anim.global_fab_menu_background_open);
        final boolean fabMenuOpen = this.fabMenuOpen;
        if (!fabMenuOpen) {
            globalFABViewBinding.globalFabMini.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            globalFABViewBinding.fabMiniLabel.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            globalFABViewBinding.fabMainLabel.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            globalFABViewBinding.fabBackground.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        fabAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                if (fabMenuOpen) {
                    globalFABViewBinding.globalFabMini.setVisibility(GONE);
                    globalFABViewBinding.fabMiniLabel.setVisibility(GONE);
                    globalFABViewBinding.fabMainLabel.setVisibility(GONE);
                        globalFABViewBinding.globalFab.setSelected(!fabMenuOpen);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (fabMenuOpen) {
                    globalFABViewBinding.fabBackground.setVisibility(GONE);
                    listener.menuDisappeared();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // Nothing to do.
            }
        });
        globalFABViewBinding.globalFabMini.startAnimation(fabAnimation);
        globalFABViewBinding.fabMiniLabel.startAnimation(labelAnimation);
        globalFABViewBinding.fabMainLabel.startAnimation(labelAnimation);
        globalFABViewBinding.fabBackground.startAnimation(backgroundAnimation);

        this.fabMenuOpen = !fabMenuOpen;
    }
```

In the animations I have fade animations for the labels and the background and a transition animation that moves my fab mini button to the place it belongs.

Now the trick to fit the background even over the status bar is, we cannot do it! So we have to find a workaround and this is not very obvious. First I thought to make the activity fullscreen but then the status bar disappears. So we have to let the status bar there but we need to make it transparent. So we see the color of the statusbar that lays behind it and can lay over our background. To do this I created a new theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:immersive">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Yes. this is exactly what I want.